# CSS / jQuery Slider slows down entire page and marquee

Tags: jquery, performance, css, marquee

I have a single page that has a CSS Marquee effect (simple transition) and an CSS Image slider (carousel):

```
function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
    setTimeout(carousel, 5000);
}
```

the marquee text:

```
<div class="marqueeUp" style="font-size: 15pt;">
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
<br /><br />
- - - - - - - - - - - -
<br /><br />
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
</div>
```

Marquee effect:

```
.marqueeUp {
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 430px;
    -moz-transform:translateY(100%);
    -webkit-transform:translateY(100%); 
    transform:translateY(100%);
    /* Apply animation to this element */   
    -moz-animation: marqueeUp 25s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: marqueeUp 25s linear infinite;
    animation: marqueeUp 25s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes marqueeUp {
    0%   { -moz-transform: translateY(100%); }
    100% { -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes marqueeUp {
    0%   { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }
}

@keyframes marqueeUp {
    0%   { 
      -moz-transform: translateY(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
      -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
      transform: translateY(100%);      
    }
    100% { 
      -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); /* Firefox bug fix */
      transform: translateY(-100%); 
    }
}
```

The thing is the everytime there is an image change, the text in the marquee get's stuck and laggs a lot.
Is there any way to create smooth image changing or marquee movement?
Or any way to make this thing work smoothly without lags..
Tried to use less resolution images and it didn't help.

Comment: Please try my plugin to do the marquee, let's see if the css animation is slowing down everything... http://tonysamperi.github.io/endlessRiver/

Comment: still everytime the image switches to the next one page freezes... i have simple real time js clock that also jumps 1-2 seconds each time the image changes.

Comment: You do _slideIndex++_ but where is declared?

Comment: 2 rows about it sorry I didn't included it.
slideIndex and slideInt are both declared

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the *Carousel* function, I would do something like this:

```
window.carousel = function(time) {
    var self = this;
    this.run = function() {
        //hide current slide
        self.slides[self.currentSlide].style.display = "none";
        self.currentSlide++;
        if (self.currentSlide >= self.slidesCount) {
            self.currentSlide = 0
        }
        self.slides[self.currentSlide].style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(self.run, self.time);
    };
    this.init = function(time) {
        self.time = time || 5000;
        self.currentSlide = 0;
        self.slides = document.getElementsByClassName("ts-slide");
        self.slidesCount = this.slides.length;
        //There's no point in having a slider with one or no slides
        if (self.slidesCount < 2) {
            console.warning("No animation");
            return false;
        }
        //Hide all slides but first
        for (var i = 1; i < this.slidesCount; i++) {
            self.slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        setTimeout(self.run, self.time);
    }(time);
};

window.carousel(5000);
```

working fiddle ==> https://jsfiddle.net/a8vrs029/

Comment: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined in [this.slides[this.currentSlide].style.display = "none";]

Comment: Check now please